# For loop with the length of array that has values

Tags: c++, arrays

Say I have an integer array called abc[100]. abc only has values in the first 5 "slots". How can I write a for loop for this where the loop goes up until the last value in abc that isnt empty?

```
int abc[100] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Comment: You mean `abc` is an array?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Your code it wrong. You declare an array of 100 integers, but initialize it with 5 pointers to `char`. Referencing the five first elements in the array will most likely result in *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, That shouldn't compile in the first place.

Comment: You could use a `boost::optional<int> abc[100]` (or replace that with `std::array` or `boost::array`).

Comment: @chris It might compile, but the compiler should certainly should warnings at the user for this.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I don't think C++ allows pointer to integer conversions at all. I think it was just (possibly an older version of) C. Maybe GCC lets you with `-fpermissive`, but I hate that option.

Comment: @abelenky Yes that's what I said, five *pointers to `char`*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ arrays, there is no concept of an array element being "empty".
That idea simply doesn't exist.  Erase it from your mind.
Each array element always exists.

In C & C++, when part of an array is explicitly initialized, and part is not explicitly initialized, the part that you didn't specify defaults to zero.

So, you effectively wrote:

```
int abc[100] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0....};
```

If you want, you can treat value `0` as a marker for values that aren't set.

```
int i;
for(i=0; abc[i] != 0; ++i)
{
    cout << "[" <<i<< "] : " << abc[i] <<endl;
}
```

Comment: (note that this means none of your values can be 0)

Comment: Except of the last value, which must be `0` or you run over the array.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ if you declare an array and initialize only the first few elements, the remaining elements will be *value initialize*, meaning basically that the "default constructor" will be called.

For built-in types such as `int` value initializing sets the value to zero. So if you fix the problems with your array, and only initialize the first five elements the remaining will be initialized to zero.